# PALLOC Linux Kernel 4.4

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cgroups

Been trying to get PALLOC(https://github.com/heechul/palloc) for cache partitioning to work on the Linux 4.4.123 kernel. We're using Ubuntu 16.04.

The problem is that we cannot create a cgroup as per ordinated by the official documentation(Attached above). We've tried running the commands, but the first one is not able to be executed. This is the return we get:

```
mount: xxx is already mounted or /sys/fs/cgroup busy
```

There are some processes hugging     /sys/fs/cgroup but when tried killing them, they just reappear.

We also tried creating a new directory in    /sys/fs/cgroup but it responds with saying that it's a read-only filesystem.

We've tried the following without any success:

1. Remounting /sys/fs/cgroup as read-write, which succeded but when creating a dir. part1 it is empty. The documentation suggests this should contain numerous files.
2. Mounting the cgroup as a temporary filesystem as per instructions of Kernel documentation(https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt). And mounted a cgroup fs to it, this worked but didn't include the file palloc.bins which PALLOC needs.

Anyone got any advice/solutions to share on the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cgroup structure for Linux is changed, as there is now a controller called 'palloc' which is where all new directories should be created. You should be able to create a new directory in the 'palloc' controller using the same mkdir command.

You could also try using the cgcreate tool to create a new directory in the 'palloc' controller by using the following command:

```
cgcreate -g palloc:part1
```

Comment: The solution worked perfectly, problem solved. Can't express my gratitude enough!

Comment: Is there any chance it is possible to include the cpuset.cpus and cpuset.mems as well? Using mkdir inside the palloc folder does not create those two files, and it seems they are read/write locked in the regular cgroup folder